# How do I set the state, of the useState, to a input button value, so whenever the value change the state changes as well?

Tags: reactjs, input, use-effect, use-state, preact

I have a page that have 8 different buttons, and what I want is that each button will give a different value, and I want to create a useState that the state will be this value generated from the button, and when the state change I want to make the useEffect read the state at real time.
[Here is my main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2VLo.png)

[The buttons are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZNSr.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's considered good practice to paste your code directly in SO, and not link to it via an image.

Comment: you could make useState as an object that contains the 8 buttons values.

Comment: Sounds like you want us to write the code for you, which is off-topic. We ***can*** help with existing code. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include as detailed as possible any information on issues, bugs, if you are stuck, something not working as expected, etc... You need to just add the `useState` hook and call the state updater with value in each button's `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You create a map in state of the buttons' names and values, like so:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});

const handleChange = e => setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

return (
   // ... all the other stuff
   <button name="button1" onChange={handleChange}>Button 1</button>
   <button name="button2" onChange={handleChange}>Button 2</button>
   <button name="button3" onChange={handleChange}>Button 3</button>
   // ... and so on
)
```

That approach will handle n number of buttons and dynamically add/update the values as you change them.